# Change User Password Page - Django

Tags: python, django

I created a profile page for the user.
In the "change password" section:

[image]

when I click on ***this form***, unfortunately, it goes to this link: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/8/password/", if I defined in the links that it should go into this link: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/password/". where is the problem from?

name of my project is "resume", and my app is "members".

resume urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("main.urls", namespace="main")),
    path("blog/", include("blog.urls", namespace="blog")),
    path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
    path("accounts/", include("members.urls")),
]
```

members urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from members.views import UserRegisterView, UserEditView, PasswordsChangeView
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name = "members"

urlpatterns = [
    path("register/", UserRegisterView.as_view(), name="register"),
    path("panel/", UserEditView.as_view(), name="panel"),
    path("password/", auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: It looks like the issue is related to the way you've included the URLs in your project's urls.py. You have included both django.contrib.auth.urls and members.urls under the same path "accounts/". This can lead to conflicts and unexpected behavior. To fix this, you can separate the URLs for authentication provided by django.contrib.auth and your custom member URLs.

Comment: Thanks @Temi. Can you explain more?  your comment was unclear to me.

Comment: Please share the profile page html. Okay in your resume urls.py, you have two urls path("accounts/", include("django.contrib.auth.urls")) and path("accounts/", include("members.urls")), both have same path (accounts/), this can lead to conflicts and unexpected behavior. You could change the members url path to members.